# Zsh doesn't save var into history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

When I test with a variable like:

```
test="abc"
```

above command didn't save into history, must I have messed up with some `setopt` but I don't know which can be affect to this.

So what zsh history opts can prevent it from saving var into zsh history? I have `HIST_NO_FUNCTIONS` set that I suspect it.

EDIT: full `setopt`

```
autocd
autonamedirs
autopushd
extendedglob
extendedhistory
noglobalrcs
histexpiredupsfirst
histfindnodups
histignorealldups
histignoredups
histignorespace
histnofunctions
histnostore
histreduceblanks
histsavenodups
histverify
incappendhistory
interactive
interactivecomments
login
magicequalsubst
monitor
nonotify
nullglob
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
pushdminus
pushdsilent
pushdtohome
rmstarsilent
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a `zsh` shell and the default options, nor by setting `HIST_NO_FUNCTIONS`. You may want to show what history-related options/variables you have set.

Comment: Thansk, I've just added full `setopts` @Kusalananda

Comment: You need to show **all** history-related settings, not just `setopt` output. This includes several variables and any `zshaddhistory` hook. Post your whole configuration.

Comment: Looks like it's because of your approach at [Don't save failed command to history?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/584869)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few days ago, in [another question](/q/584869), you said you had added to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zshaddhistory() { whence ${${(z)1}[1]} >| /dev/null || return 1 }
```

That causes command lines whose first word (with quoting included) is not the name of any existing command not to be added to the history.

`test="abc"` is not the name of an existing command on your system, so it won't get saved in the history.

That would also fail to save a command line like `"echo" "foo"`, or `<input tr a b >output`, or `(foo; bar) | baz`...

@Gilles had already warned you about that in a comment to your question there.

Comment: Seem true, I haven’t found a solution for excluding failed commands and force to add it to zshaddhistory.